# Two small problems on the FiniteDifferenceDerivative in the tutorial?

Tags: documentation, finite-difference-method

In the tutorial [for FiniteDifferenceDerivative](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) of pseudospectral approximation, there is a nice example. I just show a snapshot
[image]

The following line should define $11$ discrete wavenumbers over a domain of $L=10$. And as it uses `PeriodicInterpolation -> True`, so it includes the first wavenumber $k=0$ with `Range[0, 10]`. If using `Range[1, 10]`, should I set `PeriodicInterpolation -> False` instead?

```
ugrid = N[2 \[Pi] Range[0, 10]/10]
```

In the following line, I am wondering what is the meaning of $1$ at the 1st argument of the function? Why does it give the approximation for the 2nd-order derivative of the sine function? Isn't it the 1st-order derivative?

```
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, ugrid, Sin[ugrid], PeriodicInterpolation -> True, "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "If using Range[1, 10], should I set PeriodicInterpolation -> False instead?"? As to the second question, it' undoubtedly a typo in the document, please report it to WRI.

Comment: @xzczd I mean `ugrid = N[2 \[Pi] Range[1, 10]/10]` actually gives $10$ discrete wavenumbers (or grid points) for FFT, in which periodicity is automatically satisfied by the Fourier decomposition. Let's call them $k_1$,... $k_{10}$, the Fourier coefficient corresponds to $k_{10}$ should be equal to that of $k_0$, so I guess we do not need to set `PeriodicInterpolation -> True`.

Comment: @xzczd, as for the second question: so the `1` should mean taking 1st-order derivative. For 2nd-order derivative, one should use `2`, and so on. Am I right?

Comment: Seems that you've misunderstood the syntax of ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative`` in certain way. 2nd argument of it specifies the position where the derivative is calculated, the option value of `PeriodicInterpolation` doesn't influence it. Try e.g. ``ugrid = N[2 \[Pi] Range[0, 10]/10];
deri = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, ugrid, ugrid // Sin, 
  PeriodicInterpolation -> True, "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"];

ListPlot[{ugrid, deri}\[Transpose]]~Show~Plot[Sin'[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`` and observe. "so the 1 should mean taking 1st-order derivative... " Yes.

Comment: In my opinion "second derivative" in the cited help is simply a type and should read "frist derivative". You may verify this by either plotting the derivative data or  looking a bit later in the help where the calculated data is compared to "Cos" and not to"-sSn"